# after build any window is opened c++

Tags: c++, linux, window, codeblocks

I did a disk partition to get Linux to be able to practise with c++ and it is impossible because I don't find the error I did install code blocks.
I tried to use the xterminal but it's a bit annoying just for practice!

Every time I try to run my program in codeblocks appears this message "Can't create output directory bin/Debug/" and I cant see my program... do I have to install anything else?

my program doesn't appear after build

Comment: Apparently you've set up the C::B project to build the binaries in
a directory to which you don't have write permission. You may not understand that on Linux you have write permission only within your *home folder*, unless you work as superuser (which for normal purposes you should not). Controlling filesystem
permissions has nothing to do with C::B. You do it through your filesystem GUI or from the commandline: this is a matter of learning to use your Linux system (and off-topic for SO).

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have permission to the directory to build.

Change the `build` or `output` directory from settings of CodeBlocks then try...

Comment: i can not find this option in my settings... im getting desesperate :( thanks to answer